# Why does the Event interface have a constructor in Javascript and how to implement DOM based custom events?

Tags: javascript, events, constructor, interface, custom-events

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and while trying to implement a custom event for DOM manipulation, I came across the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) Web Docs. What caught my attention is that it's defined as an [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#:%7E:text=The%20Event-,interface,-represents%20an%20event), but it also seems to have a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#constructor) (new Event(...)). From my understanding, interfaces in other programming languages don't typically have constructors, so this concept is a bit confusing for me.

Could someone please clarify how an interface in JavaScript, like the Event interface, can have a constructor? What's the purpose of having a constructor in an interface, and how should I approach utilizing it when working with custom events?

My confusion stems from the fact that the Event is labelled as an [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#:%7E:text=The%20Event-,interface,-represents%20an%20event), yet it appears to have a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#constructor) (new Event(...)), which seems more akin to a class. My understanding of interfaces from other programming languages leads me to think that they primarily define method signatures, without constructors.

Here's what I'd like to do: design a custom event using best practices. Should I extend or implement the Event interface, or is that even the right approach? Could someone clarify whether the Event interface is closer to a class or an interface in the traditional sense? Additionally, I'd appreciate any guidance or examples on how to proceed with creating a custom event while adhering to JavaScript conventions.

Comment: I think mdn means an interface like an API. Something a developer uses.

Comment: [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 1):

MDN uses the term "interface" in the abstract, like [IDL does](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-interfaces):

> Objects are entities that have identity and which are encapsulations of state and behavior. An **interface** is a definition that declares some state and behavior that an object implementing that interface will expose.

That's the kind of interface that `Event` is - you could also call it a type declaration. And in fact, Web IDL does *only* use such `interface`s to define all its programming interfaces, which are then mapped to concrete code in different programming languages. The `Event` might be implemented as an interface, a class, a type, an abstract class, a module, or something else, depending on the programming language. In JavaScript in particular, there are no "interfaces", so `Event` becomes a global function object with a `.prototype` property - according to the [WebIDL ECMAScript binding](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#es-interfaces).

Also, `Event` was not always constructible. Back in [DOM level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/#events-Events-interface), there was no `constructor`, you instead had to create events via `document.createEvent(…).initEvent(…)` which was rather ugly.