# how intefaces in DOM API are defined and used?

Tags: javascript, interface

I know JavaScript doesn't have the concept of "interface" like Java and there is no "class X implements Y" in javaScript. But why when I look at DOM classes they talk about interface.
e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

As an example if I create a new Image Object it is both an instance of Image as well as HTMLImageElement 'interface' .

```
const img = new Image();
img instanceof Image; //true
img instanceof HTMLImageElement; //true
```

meaning that class Image has somehow implemented this interface . can someone shed more light on this subject ?

Comment: The DOM is a specification for an OOP library and is not tied to JavaScript at all: the DOM spec is defined using IDL, not JavaScript, and the IDL specification for those objects represents the interfaces. (Historical note: in the mid-1990s the DOM was available to Netscape's JavaScript (nee _LiveScript_), but also IE's VBScript and TCL; The DOM was also  exposed as a COM API on Windows so it could be used by C/C++/VB6 programs, for example.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76943748/1048572

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider in the context of web APIs like the DOM, an "interface" is more about defining a contract for what methods and properties a certain type of object (like HTMLImageElement) should have. It's not an interface in the sense of a Java interface, which is a formal construct that can be implemented by classes. JavaScript uses prototypal inheritance, not the classical inheritance you see in languages like Java.

When you create an instance of an Image, it inherits properties and methods from its prototype chain. When you create a new Image(), under the hood, JavaScript sets up the prototype chain for this object so that Image.prototype is an instance of HTMLImageElement.prototype. This is why your img instance is an instance of both Image and HTMLImageElement.

In JavaScript, the `instanceof` operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. Since HTMLImageElement is in the prototype chain of Image, `img instanceof HTMLImageElement` returns true.

Comment: I'm familiar with JS protoype chain and what instanceof does.
my question was specifically about the use of term 'interface' which does not exists in JS now appears to come from from IDL.